# Return a date but sort by name and value in Apache Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapper

Good day, I don't know if my Title is the best one but I have this list:

```
201505011000######PEN DRIVE01470
201505011000#######NOTEBOOK11470
201605011000#######NOTEBOOK21471
201705011000#######NOTEBOOK21472
201705011000###GAVETA DE HD01472
201703011000###GAVETA DE HD01473
```

Where for eg.: `201505` represent the year and the month,
after the `#` sign I had the product name, and in the and the price `01470` represent `14,70`.

What I need to do is get the lower price for each product and show the Year and month of that Price.
But I don't know to do that, what I can show are the Lower price and the product.

Here is my program:
**MAPPER**

```
package pkg.produto;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MinProdutoMapper
        extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        String ano = line.substring(0, 6);
        String produto = line.substring(13, 27);//Nome do produto
        produto = produto.substring(produto.lastIndexOf("#") + 1);
        //String produto_ano = ano+produto ;
        int valor = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(27, 32));//Valor do produto
        context.write(new Text(produto), new IntWritable(valor));
    }
}
```

**REDUCER**

```
package pkg.produto;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MinProdutoReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (IntWritable value : values) {
            minValue = Math.min(minValue, value.get());
        }
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(minValue));
    }
}
```

Can someone help?

Comment: You can give a look at secondary sort and then modify your solution. here is one link with code example which can help you solve your problem. secondary-sort

Answer (score -1):

You can give a look at secondary sort and then modify your solution. here is one link with code example which can help you solve your problem. [secondary-sort](http://codingjunkie.net/secondary-sort/)

Comment: The link that you have provided isn't sufficient to answer the question. Please post this as a comment or elaborate it to address the problem.